# Google Maps API Polygon artefacts showing on zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map, built with the JS API, that has polygons for different regions of the UK.

On Chrome (v58 and v60 tested) when the user zooms in or out with the scroll wheel random artefacts of the Polygons are getting stuck on the map.

Zooming further either removes them or shows different artefacts.

This does not happen in FireFox.

[image: Google Maps artefacts]

Anybody experienced this before and found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem with polygons, not with zooms but polygons clicks, I think it's definitively a chrome bug.

[Google Map Data Layer, click on polygon and change opacity (Chrome Bug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570595/google-map-data-layer-click-on-polygon-and-change-opacity-chrome-bug)

Answer (score 1):

For your reference, the problem is reported in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38211242

I believe Google is aware of the issue and looking into it. Please feel free to star a public bug to add your votes.

**UPDATE**

As stated in Google issue tracker, the issue was fixed in Chrome 60. The corresponding bug was marked as Fixed on August 9, 2017.